# How to connect many computers without a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ad-hoc-network

I am trying to write an application that collects data input from 6 people sitting on 6 computers. This data needs to be compiled together from the 6 computers to be analyzed. When we use this application, we will be in a venue where there will be no WiFi and we are prohibited from making our own networks such as setting up our own router or creating a wireless ad-hoc network.

How can I connect 6 client computers to a 7th master computer and send data without any WiFi or ad-hoc networks to analyze said data in the master computer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link them all together with a simple network switch, you will just need to allocate each of them a static IP address if you don't plan to use a DHCP server.

Comment: that wouldn't be wireless though, right?

Comment: also, what is a `DHCP Server` and can I configure one on the master computer?

Comment: No. It's a device you plug ethernet cables into and will allow packet transmission between each device. [It looks like this](http://www.computeralliance.com.au/InventoryImages/3480.jpg). A DHCP server allocates IP addresses to clients. Honestly, you won't need one for such a small set up, just give each client a static private address. 192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.7 would do fine.

Comment: Alright. And how would i give each client that? Do I do that programmatically, or is it in the OS configuration of that master computer?

Comment: You do it in the network settings of each machine. It only has to be done once on the initial setting up. Search for set static IP for your OS, there are lots of guides.

Comment: How does this "answer" conform to the stipulation of no *"ad-hoc network"*?

Comment: @sawdust - Because the OP specifies "wireless ad-hoc network". Later he mentioned "ad-hoc network" alone, but I took this to be shorthand of "wireless ad-hoc network" again, as this was his original requirement. I'm not sure my "answer" is wrong, but the original question somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Fair enough.  I missed the first occurrence..